# My job description never changed, though I had to be certified by the state to have this position

Tags: promotion, job-description

I've been working for 20 years for the same company.  I was hired as a Certified Nursing Assistant 20 years ago. My requirements were assisting patients with their daily activities, showers and so on. 11 years ago my job changed to a higher position, which required classes, tests and a certificate from the State Boards to work as a Medtech/supervisor.

I just found that my job description states Certified Nursing Assistant, but all other Medtechs who came after are listed as Medtech/supervisor. I am now in a battle over getting this changed with HR and Managers, and I've been getting a lot of run around from them. Medtechs make more money than CNA's so I am guessing after 11 years this is a big issue. How can I argue for this change without it hurting my job?

Comment: The OP wants a change of job title I think and a job description that actually fits with their duties.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to edit it the best i could. Hope this is better.

Comment: Adding country / state might help in this case. These things might be different per region. For example if it comes to getting payed, you would think what you actually do (Your worth) is more importend then what the name of your function is. This might however be different per region and even company/branch.

Comment: @Charlie, much improved. Are your job duties the same as the other medtechs? Do you get paid less than them? What reason is your manager giving for not wanting to change your title?

Comment: My duties are the same as all other Medtechs. Our company cleaned house and we got a new manager, director of nursing, administrator and HR just this past year. my manager stated it was a higher pay and wow they owe you some money. She put in for the change a month ago. Nothing has been said or happened as of yet. My Director of Nursing excuse was well they go by what I was originally hired for. I guess she thinks us employees are stupid. I would like to know where all my records are from before they all came. I live in NC. should i pursue this.

Answer (score 2):

> My manager stated it was a higher pay and wow they owe you some money. She put in for the change a month ago.

From your quoted comment it sounds like your manager is on your side. I would continue to work through your manager for the time being. A good manager is one who goes to bat for you. See how willing they are to fight for you.

At the same time, you must understand that your manager can only go so far if the rest of the people up the chain are unwilling to move. You have the certifications and training. You should start exploring what your skills are worth in the open job market.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am 64 yrs old now and love my job. After 20 years of service at this point i am not going to change jobs. I will be thinking of retireing in the next few years. I don't know if I should just let this drop. or go further with it. But at the same time it is very depressing to know I am not actually being recognized for what i have been doing for the past 11 years. My manager is ok, but she doe's what her boss says. Should I go to HR. or will that be making to much waves.

Comment: @Charlie I feel for you, and I can totally understand not wanting to leave your current employer. "_Should I go to HR. or will that be making to much waves._" It is impossible for us to know what that would do. What is your current manager saying as to why it is taking so long and how much longer it will take?

Comment: @ mikeazo The problem is my manager manages another unit and is never on our floor. Sometimes I see her in passing on her way home as She is leaving when I come in. I have tried to get in touch with her, but she is always unavailable. She more or less lets us manage our floor. In a way we really have no manager. HR is the same. you have to make an apt.  I call, the machine say's leave a message. They never get back to me. They are only there 2 days 8-10 am I appreciate all the reply's but i am thinking there is no solution without making waves. So I have to decide to either do that or let go.